# Why am I failing to interact with a smart contract I found on Etherscan.io?

Tags: web3js, ganache, smart-contract-wallets, web3-providers

I am getting the below error trying to call an existing smart contract I found on Etherscan.io function using call().

> Error: Error: Returned values aren't valid, did it run Out of Gas? You
> might also see this error if you are not using the correct ABI for the
> contract you are retrieving data from, requesting data from a block
> number that does not exist, or querying a node which is not fully
> synced.

The contract, which isn't deployed by me, can be found here [on etherscan.io](https://etherscan.io/address/0x2929e21109901461659c0f26ad7f0e7633ea6539#readContract):

Below is how I have configured my web3.0 and integrated the smart contract into my Dapp:

```
if(typeof web3 !== 'undefined'){
    web3 = new Web3(ethereum);
  }
else
  {
    web3 = new Web3(new Web3.provider.HttpProviders("HTTP://127.0.0.1:7545")); 
    alert("web3 is now: " +web3);
  }

web3.eth.defaultAccount  = web3.eth.accounts[0];

//##### The smart contract from Etherscan.io #####
//################################################ 
var DateTimeContractAbi = [{"constant":true,"inputs":[{"name":"timestamp","type":"uint256"}],"name":"getHour","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"uint8"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"pure","type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[{"name":"timestamp","type":"uint256"}],"name":"getWeekday","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"uint8"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"pure","type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[{"name":"year","type":"uint16"},{"name":"month","type":"uint8"},{"name":"day","type":"uint8"},{"name":"hour","type":"uint8"},{"name":"minute","type":"uint8"}],"name":"toTimestamp","outputs":[{"name":"timestamp","type":"uint256"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"pure","type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[{"name":"timestamp","type":"uint256"}],"name":"getDay","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"uint8"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"pure","type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[{"name":"year","type":"uint16"},{"name":"month","type":"uint8"},{"name":"day","type":"uint8"},{"name":"hour","type":"uint8"}],"name":"toTimestamp","outputs":[{"name":"timestamp","type":"uint256"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"pure","type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[{"name":"timestamp","type":"uint256"}],"name":"getSecond","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"uint8"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"pure","type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[{"name":"year","type":"uint16"},{"name":"month","type":"uint8"},{"name":"day","type":"uint8"}],"name":"toTimestamp","outputs":[{"name":"timestamp","type":"uint256"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"pure","type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[{"name":"year","type":"uint16"},{"name":"month","type":"uint8"},{"name":"day","type":"uint8"},{"name":"hour","type":"uint8"},{"name":"minute","type":"uint8"},{"name":"second","type":"uint8"}],"name":"toTimestamp","outputs":[{"name":"timestamp","type":"uint256"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"pure","type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[{"name":"timestamp","type":"uint256"}],"name":"getYear","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"uint16"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"pure","type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[{"name":"timestamp","type":"uint256"}],"name":"getMonth","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"uint8"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"pure","type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[{"name":"year","type":"uint16"}],"name":"isLeapYear","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"bool"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"pure","type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[{"name":"year","type":"uint256"}],"name":"leapYearsBefore","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"uint256"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"pure","type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[{"name":"month","type":"uint8"},{"name":"year","type":"uint16"}],"name":"getDaysInMonth","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"uint8"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"pure","type":"function"},{"constant":true,"inputs":[{"name":"timestamp","type":"uint256"}],"name":"getMinute","outputs":[{"name":"","type":"uint8"}],"payable":false,"stateMutability":"pure","type":"function"}];
var DateTimeContractAddress = '0x2929E21109901461659C0F26aD7f0e7633Ea6539';
var DateTimeContract = new web3.eth.Contract(DateTimeContractAbi, DateTimeContractAddress);
var DateTimeMethods = DateTimeContract.methods;

console.log ("DateTimeMethods: ", DateTimeMethods);

//##### My smart contract from Remix IDE #####
//############################################
var cryptpGiftContractAbi = [{"inputs":[],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"constructor"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":true,"internalType":"address","name":"owner","type":"address"},{"indexed":true,"internalType":"address","name":"approved","type":"address"},{"indexed":true,"internalType":"uint256","name":"tokenId","type":"uint256"}],"name":"Approval","type":"event"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":true,"internalType":"address","name":"owner","type":"address"},{"indexed":true,"internalType":"address","name":"operator","type":"address"},{"indexed":false,"internalType":"bool","name":"approved","type":"bool"}],"name":"ApprovalForAll","type":"event"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"to","type":"address"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"tokenId","type":"uint256"}],"name":"approve","outputs":[],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"_to","type":"address"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"_tokenId","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"string","name":"_messageToRecipient","type":"string"}],"name":"editMyGifts","outputs":[],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"_tokenId","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"_extendTimeBy","type":"uint256"}],"name":"extendTime","outputs":[],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"_tokenId","type":"uint256"}],"name":"mintNFTtoken","outputs":[],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"_giftOwnersAddress","type":"address"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"_tokenId","type":"uint256"}],"name":"processGifting","outputs":[],"stateMutability":"payable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"from","type":"address"},{"internalType":"address","name":"to","type":"address"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"tokenId","type":"uint256"}],"name":"safeTransferFrom","outputs":[],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"from","type":"address"},{"internalType":"address","name":"to","type":"address"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"tokenId","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"bytes","name":"_data","type":"bytes"}],"name":"safeTransferFrom","outputs":[],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"operator","type":"address"},{"internalType":"bool","name":"approved","type":"bool"}],"name":"setApprovalForAll","outputs":[],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"_to","type":"address"},{"internalType":"string","name":"_tokenName","type":"string"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"_tokenId","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"string","name":"_messageToRecipient","type":"string"}],"name":"setGiftRecipient","outputs":[],"stateMutability":"payable","type":"function"},{"anonymous":false,"inputs":[{"indexed":true,"internalType":"address","name":"from","type":"address"},{"indexed":true,"internalType":"address","name":"to","type":"address"},{"indexed":true,"internalType":"uint256","name":"tokenId","type":"uint256"}],"name":"Transfer","type":"event"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"from","type":"address"},{"internalType":"address","name":"to","type":"address"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"tokenId","type":"uint256"}],"name":"transferFrom","outputs":[],"stateMutability":"nonpayable","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"owner","type":"address"}],"name":"balanceOf","outputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"","type":"uint256"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"tokenId","type":"uint256"}],"name":"getApproved","outputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"","type":"address"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[],"name":"getGiftStatus","outputs":[{"internalType":"enum etherGifter.Status","name":"","type":"uint8"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[],"name":"giftCount","outputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"","type":"uint256"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"","type":"address"}],"name":"gifts","outputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"from","type":"address"},{"internalType":"address","name":"to","type":"address"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"tokenId","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"string","name":"tokenName","type":"string"},{"internalType":"string","name":"messageToRecipient","type":"string"},{"internalType":"enum etherGifter.Status","name":"GiftStatus","type":"uint8"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"createdAt","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"firstReminderAt","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"transferDate","type":"uint256"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"","type":"uint256"}],"name":"giftsByToken","outputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"from","type":"address"},{"internalType":"address","name":"to","type":"address"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"tokenId","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"string","name":"tokenName","type":"string"},{"internalType":"string","name":"messageToRecipient","type":"string"},{"internalType":"enum etherGifter.Status","name":"GiftStatus","type":"uint8"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"createdAt","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"firstReminderAt","type":"uint256"},{"internalType":"uint256","name":"transferDate","type":"uint256"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"owner","type":"address"},{"internalType":"address","name":"operator","type":"address"}],"name":"isApprovedForAll","outputs":[{"internalType":"bool","name":"","type":"bool"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[],"name":"name","outputs":[{"internalType":"string","name":"","type":"string"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"tokenId","type":"uint256"}],"name":"ownerOf","outputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"","type":"address"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"address","name":"_giftOwnersAddress","type":"address"}],"name":"recieveAddress","outputs":[{"internalType":"string","name":"","type":"string"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"bytes4","name":"interfaceId","type":"bytes4"}],"name":"supportsInterface","outputs":[{"internalType":"bool","name":"","type":"bool"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[],"name":"symbol","outputs":[{"internalType":"string","name":"","type":"string"}],"stateMutability":"view","type":"function"},{"inputs":[{"internalType":"uint256","name":"tokenId","type":"uint256"}],"name":"tokenURI","outputs":[{"internalType":"string","name":"","type":"string"}],"stateMutability":"view..."}];
var cryptpGiftContractAddress = '0xA90551f8684B4a5C10648141528A12287c59f03E'; 
var cryptpGiftContract = new web3.eth.Contract(cryptpGiftContractAbi, cryptpGiftContractAddress);
var cryptpGiftMethods = cryptpGiftContract.methods;
```

> Kindly NOTE that in reference to the code above, I have connected two
> different smart contracts to my Dapp, one of them, namely the
> `**cryptpGiftContract**` is my own and works perfectly. It lives on
> the **Remix IDE**, under **Environment Web3 Provider**, which also means am
> connected to the **Ganache** and not the mainnet. I am able to successfully call all
> the methods on my smart contract, so the issue here **isnt** my smart contract, rather > why I am **NOT** able to connect to the `DateTimeContract` contract.

At this point, I am certain that my integration is successful because the `console.log ("DateTimeMethods: ", DateTimeMethods);` yeilds:

[image: the yeilds of console.log ("DateTimeMethods: ", DateTimeMethods);]

Which reflect all smart contract methods at: [all the smart contracts](https://etherscan.io/address/0x2929e21109901461659c0f26ad7f0e7633ea6539#readContract)

However when I call the `getDay()` method, as illustrated below:

```
await DateTimeMethods.getDay("1652443717").call( ({from: ethAddresss}), (error, result)=> {
    console.log("Your in DateTimeMethods"); 
    console.log("Result: " +result);
    console.log("Error: " +error);
    if(!error){ }
    else{}
});
```

...this is the result I get:

> Your in DateTimeMethods
>
> ethAddresss: 0xbcc3594a11a7fd838b34bab789d246d918f2dab2
>
> Result: undefined
>
> Error: Error: Returned values aren't valid, did
> it run Out of Gas? You might also see this error if you are not using
> the correct ABI for the contract you are retrieving data from,
> requesting data from a block number that does not exist, or querying a
> node which is not fully synced.

Also `web3.min.js:22` errors out the below in the console.

> web3.min.js:22 Uncaught (in promise) Error: Returned values aren't
> valid, did it run Out of Gas? You might also see this error if you are
> not using the correct ABI for the contract you are retrieving data
> from, requesting data from a block number that does not exist, or
> querying a node which is not fully synced.

Kindly help me understand what the issue might be.

Answer (score 1):

That's because nothing is deployed in your Ganache's address `0x2929E21109901461659C0F26aD7f0e7633Ea6539`.

You need to execute this on mainnet, to receive an answer from that contract.

Comment: In an attempt to fork it as you suggested, my personal smart contract was compiled using the version: 0.8.13+commit.abaa5c0e, while the `DateTimeContract` contract am trying to fork was compiled using compiler version: 0.4.26+commit.4563c3fc. Wouldn't this create a version conflict?

Comment: If it's already compiled, there shouldn't be an issue. Feel free to accept the answer if it helped.

Comment: There is an issue though, after I forked it, am not able to use the Date time functions.

Comment: That's a different issue, start a new question with details relevant to that new issue.

Comment: sure thing. Do you have time to chat a little?